# Multiple VH tags - Performance

Tags: css

When I use multiple VH tags, my content seems to jump around on mobile. Is there any way to avoid this, also is there a way to make the scrolling smoother vs being jumpy and horrible?

VH usage is as follows:

```
.wrap {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a demo link?

Comment: http://ericerk.com/demo/ It's just a simple demo.

Comment: Looks like the reason this is happening on mobile is because the address bar moves away when the user scrolls. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944925/background-image-jumps-when-address-bar-hides-ios-android-mobile-chrome

Comment: Is there a way to smoothen out scrolling, not agnostic of platform?

Comment: This can be done with jquery. There are some plugins out there to do this, [like this one](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html) however be cautious when doing this. Affecting the default scroll behaviour to something beyond what the user is expecting can cause a negative user experince