# Chrome Android - process CSS and JS while scrolling

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

I noticed that no scripts or styles are updating while user scrolls a page. Unfortunately this causes menu with `position: fixed` and `top: 0` to jump when Chrome Android hides address bar.

So, is there any way to force CSS updates while scrolling?
Or is there any way to keep `position: fixed`, `top: 0` block on the same height?

Solutions from 'Background..' theme aren't working for me. My problem is different - Chrome Android doesn't want to update a page while user scrolls it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background image jumps when address bar hides iOS/Android/Mobile Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944925/background-image-jumps-when-address-bar-hides-ios-android-mobile-chrome)

Comment: None of solutions from that page work for me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe force a redraw by resizing it?

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580/force-dom-redraw-refresh-on-chrome-mac) for more possible solutions.

Comment: And where should I put this?
While user scrolls the page none of CSS or even JS events are happening. But I need to redraw WHILE he scrolls the page.

Comment: Well since I don't know how your code is structured, I can't say. But this is a recurring statement. You could also go for just JS - `window.onresize = function() {
    // do a load of stuff
};`

Comment: Resize event isn't firing continuously while addres bar is hiding. It fires once it disappeared. And when that happens, my menu just jumps to the right position.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes).

Comment: `transform: translateZ(0)` fixes this problem, but creates another one - now menu size is broken, because transform creates an isolated context (so now instead of viewport size for `top: 0; bottom: 0` it uses sizes of parent element)