# Visible Mobile URL Bar and Smooth Vertical Transitions between Elements - CSS JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

**SEE BELOW UPDATE**

**LOOK AT THIS SITE AND CHECK ATTACHED IMAGE -->** https://www.blinker.com/

If you see, the elements **transition vertically in a smooth way** on both computers and mobile devices.

They seem to have a full height based on the view-port something like the CSS rule below which is something easy to do and which accomplish full height based on viewport.

```
element {
height: 100vh;
}
```

**But I am trying to do the scrolling thing.**

When they scroll between each section or each element or div.

The transition goes like very smooth either by clicking on the right circle links or by doing it with your fingers on a mobile device.

*(Make reference to #1 inside the image)*

**#1 - Can someone knows how to do this?**

Also if you notice, on that site the Mobile URL Bar is always visible.

It is like they refresh the page every time, see how the favicon re-uploads every time when you go through each section.

*(Make reference to #2 inside the image)*

**#2 - How I can accomplish that?**

[image]

**RESOLVED**

I used this pure JS solution, it solved both problems.

https://github.com/peachananr/purejs-onepage-scroll

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background image jumps when address bar hides iOS/Android/Mobile Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944925/background-image-jumps-when-address-bar-hides-ios-android-mobile-chrome)

Comment: Specifically look at this answer to see how to always display the url bar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33455377/5463842

Comment: No, neither of those suggestions get close to what I just described. thanks

Comment: Found solution and I just update