# Background image rendering on Mobile

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, browser

I created a simple HTML page that displays the problem.
With Chrome desktop version is okay but trying on different mobile device and with different browsers it becomes obvious that there is a bug.

Scrolling down, in my example with Samsung S6 and Chrome, appear a white band on the bottom of the screen that disappears after less than one second.

I believe this problem is generated from the header of Chrome (or browser you use) that disappears when you scroll down.

I created an example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kL7z1z7u/) and loaded the [HTML](http://yobre.com/wtf/fixed_WTF.html) page on my server.

On the web I did not find answers to my question, I hope someone is able to help me.
Thank you all in advance.

Tests performed (and failed) with:

```
Samsung S6 and Chrome
Samsung S6 and Samsung Browser
IPhone 6S and Safari
LG G4 and Chrome
LG G4 and LG Browser
```

Comment: The same question, check it please - [decision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944925/background-image-jumps-when-address-bar-hides-ios-android-mobile-chrome)

Comment: @arturmoroz I swear I had tried but had not found! Thanks so much for letting forwarded the link .. I found the solution to my problem